# XPath for nested element

Tags: xpath

I have a nested element i want to match with XPath expression - the phrase `content to match`. The code snippet with the target element looks like:

```
<div class="a">
    <span class="b">
        <span class="c">some content</span>
    content to match
    </span>  
</div>
```

I tried some expressions but failed with them. These were:

```
//div[@class="a"]/span[1]/text()
```

and

```
//span[@class="b"]/text()
```

What is my error? Could you correct my expression?

ps: i think i already had very similar cases, and the same expressions worked for me - just wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `count(//span[@class="b"]/text())` to see that `span` contains 2 text nodes: empty string (text node preceding to child `span`) and `"content to match"`. Most tools would return you the first node of `//span[@class="b"]/text()` - empty string

So try either

```
//div[@class="a"]/span/span/following-sibling::text()
```

or

```
//span[@class="b"]/text()[last()]
```

Comment: Thanks. This expression finally worked for me: `normalize-space(//span[@class="b"]/text()[last()])`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it - and get a cleaned up text is:

```
normalize-space(//text()[normalize-space(.)][../span[@class="c"]])
```

Exact output:

```
content to match
```